# Specified cast is not valid using MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the two following *web.config* file. The first one [1] is running smooth but when I replace it with the second [2] one it's give me and error. I'm using MVC 4.

[1] :

```
<add name="DBName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

[2]:  When I replace the above with the below I got an error that says "**Specified cast is not valid**"

```
<add name="DBName" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=Username;Password=Password;Connection Timeout=120" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer definitively with what you've provided, but that particular exception only occurs when a particular table column is of a type that cannot be cast to the type of the property that represents it. If this only happens when you switch between databases, then that means that your schemas of your two database do not match. Ensure that they both have *exactly* the same schemas, and you'll be fine.